# Remover caracteres não numéricos de uma string em Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Vamos supor, tenho:

```
a = "0LÁM@UN@D0
```

Eu gostaria de algo que remova o todas as letras (A-Z) e outros caracteres, só quero que fique os números, no exemplo, ficaria apenas 0 e 0

```
b = "A1B2C3"
```

Algo que tire as letras do alfabetos e caracteres, que delete tudo que não seja números (inteiros) em um *string*.

Estou usando o Python 2.7

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você pode usar *regex* para resolver seu problema:

```
import re
b = "A1B2C3"
b = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', b)

# 123
print(b)
```

### Explicação

A função `sub()`, recebe primeiro um padrão no primeiro parâmetro, uma nova `string` que irá ser usada para substituir quando achar esse padrão na `string` no segundo parâmetro, e no último parâmetro a `string` que você quer procurar o padrão.

### Regex

No primeiro parâmetro estamos passando uma *regex* para retirar tudo que não for número da string, uma breve explicação sobre ela:

`[0-9]`:  irá pegar todos os dígitos de 0 até 9

`[^0-9]` : irá pegar tudo que não for dígito

Comment: Parabéns pela resposta. É comum vermos aqui gente que tenta ajudar, mas coloca respostas que excluem a sua parte da "explicação": só dizem "você pode usar essa regex: ..." ...e isso não ajuda muito.

Comment: @jsbueno Obrigado! Eu sei bem como é isso, pois já levei esse tipo de resposta algumas vezes hehe.

Comment: Marcelo obrigado! Por favor, se possível me responda algo.
É se eu quiser remover apenas todos os caracteres especiais?

Comment: Muito obrigado Marcelo! :D ajudou MUITO!

Answer (score 5):

Uma alternativa à resposta do Marcelo é fazer um join apenas do que for dígito:

```
>>> a = "0LÁM@UN@D0"
>>> b = "A1B2C3"
>>> ''.join(c for c in a if c.isdigit())
'00'
>>> ''.join(c for c in b if c.isdigit())
'123'
>>>
```

Comment: Obrigadoooo :D!

Answer (score 1):

Outra possível forma de resolver tal questão é utilizando a função **[filter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#filter)** associada com **[lambda](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html#lambda)**. Desta forma o código ficaria:

```
s = input('Digite uma string: ')
resultado = ''.join(filter(lambda i: i if i.isdigit() else None, s))

print(resultado)
```

**Testando o código:**

Ao executar o referido código e digitarmos...

```
A1B2C3
```

...e pressionarmos <kbd>Enter</kbd>, receberemos como saída:

```
123
```