# Como remover caracteres indesejados de uma lista de strings?

Tags: python

Sou novo em python e não consegui achar uma resposta para minha dúvida.
Recebo uma lista de textos do banco de dados e o transformo em uma lista de strings conforme abaixo:

```
textosPuros = df['texto']
# print(textosPuros)

textoMinusculo = textosPuros.str.lower().str.split(' ')

# print(textoMinusculo)

textoLimpo = [item for item in textoMinusculo if item not in ['\n', '\t', '/', '.', '-', '(', ')']]
```

Numa tentativa de limpar as strings para que possa trabalhar com elas normalizadas, implementei a última linha, mas, mesmo assim, tenho caracteres ruins:

```
[['\testá', 'tossindo', 'noite.mãe', 'fez', 'inalação', 'com', 'berotec', 'essa', 'noite,com', 'melhora', '.está', 'usando', 'o', 'piemonte', 'há', '2', 'cuidou', '', ',', '----', 'com', '', 'febre.é', 'muito', 'ansioso', 'e', 'agitado.\nex.f:beg', 'corado,com', 'taquipnéia', 'leve', 'afebril', 's/sinais', 'meníngeos', 'otosc:nl', 'cavum:hiperemia', 'pulmões:esc+sibilos', 'abdome', 'nl\t'],['mais strings','episódio\n\nap\n-','\t0000000000\t'],['outra lista','menopausea.\n\nexames']]
```

Como faço para retirar estes caracteres indesejados? Como

> \t \n : . , - _

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como remover caracteres de uma string?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120389/como-remover-caracteres-de-uma-string)

Comment: [Remover caracteres não numéricos de uma string em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/254748/5878)

Comment: boa tarde amigo, veja se isso te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251378/replace-n-in-a-string-in-python-2-7

Comment: @Anderson, é uma lista não uma string simples

Comment: @HenriqueMendes se é uma lista de string, basta percorrer a lista e aplicar as soluções dadas. Não muda praticamente nada.

Comment: Ele me retorna um erro : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace' sempre que tentei

Comment: Eu preciso retornar este valor para a lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto deve funcionar

```
novo = []
for x in lista:
    item = x
    for y in ['\n', '\t', '/', '.', '-', '(', ')']:
        item = item.replace(y, "")
    novo.append(item)
```

ou

```
novo = []
for x in lista:
    novo.append(x.translate(None, "\n\t/.-()"))
```

Comment: A primeira resolveu bastante coisa sim! Muito obrigado!